# General Quick fork() explanation

Tags: c, fork

suppose if we have something like this:

```
printf("A");
fork();
printf("B");
```

Is the output going to be

1) ABAB
 2) ABB

Can you please explain?

Comment: This sounds like something you can just quickly try yourself, no?

Comment: @DanFego And it seems that he has tried it, no wonder he gave 2 sample outputs...  He cannot just guess that "ABB" will be outputted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right answer is that it depends on the buffering mode of stdout, which the other answers seem to be ignoring.

When you fork with unflushed buffers and then continue using stdio in both processes (instead of the usual quick `execve` or `_exit` in the child process), the stuff that was in the buffer at the time of the fork can be printed twice, once by each process.

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined and `ABB`, `ABAB` and `AABB` is possible.  First (`ABB`) can happen on unbuffered output only; with buffered output both processes will have the `A` in their output buffer.  By calling `fflush(3)` before the `fork(2)` you can enforce this behavior.

Order of last chars depends on order of execution; most likely you will get `ABAB` as in this short example the program won't be interrupted by the scheduler.

Comment: "*First (ABB) can happen ...*" shouldn't it read: "*... will happen ...*"?

Comment: And for buffered output the number of possible permutations of the two occurences of `A` and `B` each is very well defined and limited.

Answer (score 0):

The output should read as "ABB"
fork copies the entire program into a new memory space and continues from the fork. Since both processes are running the same code, I would save the process id that is returned from fork, so the rest of your program knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

the output is simply abb. Fork  create one new child process so after execution of fork() two process will run and generally child process first get the chance to executes. See before fork only one process so the out put before fork only once A. Then fork executes and hence two different process now running each will print B  and hence output is ABB.